# cut command complement in AIX is not working

Tags: shell, unix, aix

I have an CUT command in my bash script

```
cut --complement -c 1-5 file.txt > tmp
```

this command work in all unix environment except in AIX

if i execute the command in AIX i get the below error.

```
cut: Not a recognized flag: -
Usage: cut -b List [-n] [File...]
   or: cut -c List [File...]
   or: cut -f List [-d Character] [-s] [File...]
 cut: Not a recognized flag: -
bash: cut:: command not found
```

the shell script that i have will get the range eg 1-5 which is the range that needs to be trimmed off, it can be any range.

Answer (score 0):

Correct. [AIX `cut`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_71/c_commands/cut.html) does not have that option (which is a [GNU extension](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/cut-invocation.html)).

The GNU/Linux userspace has evolved significantly, AIX less so. But even AIX `cut` offers more than [required by POSIX](https://helpmanual.io/man1/cut-posix/). If you want to keep your scripts portable, you will have to find the smallest common denominator... or install those parts of the GNU/Linux userspace you need on AIX. The [AIX Toolbox for Linux Applications](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/aix-toolbox-linux-applications-overview) provides a collection of packages. (`cut` being a part of coreutils.)

Comment: is there any alternative for --complement in AIX

Comment: @Rasmi: There are always other ways to reach your goal. You could look at `awk`, or `perl`, for example. You could install the GNU coreutils from the [AIX Toolbox for Linux Applications](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/aix-toolbox-linux-applications-overview). AIX `cut`, however, will not float your boat in this case. (See updated answer.)